# Laravel 4 and MySQL: Need LIKE strategy and DB::select not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table full of leads from people who want to do business with us.  I also have a table of spam terms.  I need to filter the spam from the leads.  I'm doing this in Laravel 4.  I was thinking of something like this:

```
$spam_terms = SpamTerms::all();

$sm = '"SELECT * FROM all_forms_send_message';
foreach ($spam_terms as $spam) {
    if ($spam->id == 1) {
            $sm .= ' WHERE GeneralNotes NOT LIKE ' . $spam->term  . ' ';
    } else {
            $sm .= ' AND WHERE GeneralNotes NOT LIKE ' . $spam->term  . ' ';
    }
}
$sm .= '"';
// echo $sm;
return DB::select(DB::raw($sm));
```

First of all, this doesn't work.  It throws an error on the last line.  The statement is built just fine and `echo`s properly.

Second, is this the best way to match the leads against the spam table?  Potentially, there could be hundreds of where clauses as the spam table grows.  Is there a better strategy?

Comment: You're probably better off researching spam filtering methods (whether on S.O. or elsewhere) separate from the Lara4 question.  Not only is the two-part question not optimal for S.O, the likelihood that Laravel experts are also spam filtering experts is low.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the "AND WHERE" in the second part of the if statement and replace it with just "AND"

Without knowing more about the issue (such as the error message), it seems that's the most obvious syntax issue.

edit: to answer the larger question, I don't think this is the best way to do it. I'll let the experts hit on that part, but I would probably load all the records and all the spam rules and do the filtering after the DB queries. SQL isn't great at full-text searching, IME.

Comment: Good to know.  I'm unfortunately not getting an error message because I'm doing this asynchronously and nothing is coming back from the server.

Comment: Did you try removing the "WHERE" from "AND WHERE"?  "AND WHERE ..." is not valid SQL.

Comment: Yes, I did.  The issue is my last line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do:

`DB::select(DB::raw($sm));`

Try changing that to:

`DB::raw($sm);`

Also, why do you have double quotes in your sql statement?

Comment: I removed the quotes.  I thought I needed them.  Your second line of code just returns the SQL.

Comment: Put the select statement now you removed the quotes. Does that help?

Comment: No.  In both cases, I get `UnexpectedValueException: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "array" given.`

Comment: Even with the where clauses commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: untested code ahead...

If you're going to use the query builder, use it for the whole thing.

```
$query = DB::table('all_forms_send_message);
foreach ($spam_terms as $spam) {
    $query = $query->where('GeneralNotes','like',"%".$spam->term."%");
}
return $query->get();
```

It's a little unusual to see all the database methods "unchained," but they work fine that way.  Here you're selecting your table, adding all your where clauses and finally telling the query to run.